# How to find and highlight string if it contains "SEP" or "SIP" in the first three characters?

Tags: excel, vba, string, find

I have a range of Cisco mac addresses located in the first column of the first sheet of my workbook. I am looking to highlight data in this range that doesn't begin with SEP or SIP. It will be the first three characters in the string.

```
Dim macRange As Range
Dim macCell As Range

Columns("A:A").Select
Set macRange = Selection
For Each macCell In macRange
    If Not IsEmpty(macCell) Then
        If Left(macCell.Value, 3) not like "*[SEP]*" or "*[SIP]*" Then macCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    End If
Next macCell
```

Obviously this doesn't work but I am struggling to find a relative alternative.

Comment: You can do this with conditional formatting. Is VBA required?

Comment: `Left(macCell.Value, 3) <> "SEP" And  Left(macCell.Value, 3) <>  "SIP"`

Comment: I am using vba to import data into a vba created workbook. I need vba to apply the formating, it will be a new book every time.

Comment: Thank you Scott. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `left()` with `like` operator (`[]` not required either). if you need to check that string starts from specific text then use `"pattern*"`, in case you need to check last characters use `"*pattern"`, and if you want to check that string contains the specific text then use `"*pattern*"` (or several `"*pattern1*pattern2*pattern3*"`). also, please note that `like` is case sensitive operator (to remove case sensitivity you can use `Lcase()`, `Ucase()` or `Option Compare Text`) .
Your updated code is below:

```
Sub test0()
    Dim macRange As Range, macCell As Range
    Set macRange = Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    For Each macCell In macRange
        With macCell
            If Not (.Value Like "SEP*" Or .Value Like "SIP*") And .Value <> "" Then
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            End If
        End With
    Next macCell
End Sub
```

or like this:

```
Sub test1()
    Dim macRange As Range, macCell As Range
    Set macRange = Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    For Each macCell In macRange
        With macCell
            If .Value <> "" And Not "SEP|SIP" Like "*" & Left(.Value, 3) & "*" Then
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            End If
        End With
    Next macCell
End Sub
```

additional variants:

using `select case ...`:

```
Option Compare Text 'if you need to remove case sensitivity

Sub test2()
    Dim macRange As Range, macCell As Range
    Set macRange = Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    For Each macCell In macRange
        Select Case Left(macCell.Value, 3)
            Case "SEP", "SIP", "" 'list values that should be ignored
            Case Else: macCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        End Select
    Next macCell
End Sub
```

using dictionary:

```
Sub test3()
    Dim macRange As Range, macCell As Range, dic As Object
    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dic.comparemode = vbTextCompare 'use in case when you need to remove case sensitivity for dictionary
    dic.Add "SEP", ""
    dic.Add "SIP", ""
    dic.Add "", ""
    Set macRange = Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    For Each macCell In macRange
        If Not dic.exists(Left(macCell.Value, 3)) Then macCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    Next macCell
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the Select Case version case sensitive as well? When listing values, does I need to include "SEP" and "sep"?

Comment: @PMNIServ1 to remove case sensitivity you can add `Option Compare Text` at the top of the module (see updated post), or  apply upper case `Ucase(Left(macCell.Value, 3))` or lower case `Lcase(Left(macCell.Value, 3))`